# javascript drag a div if you click in a subsection of this div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, interact.js

I am developing this javascript application that when you open there a few svg components that have click listeners. The idea is that most (maybe all) of them will need to display information at the same time and I would like the user to choose what information he can see simultaneously because certainly all will not fit in the screen. So my idea was to use a div that you can drag but also interact with the content (and multiple of these divs could be open at any time.

I have tried some of the jQuery UI stuff but that does not seem to do the trick, the closest thing I could find there was a pop-up that blocks the rest of the site content.

I decided to go for interactjs that basically just gives me draggable and resizable divs, which is great! Unfortunately, I could not find how to make just certain parts of the divs draggable (like the top of the window that actually drags the window in your regular OS) and how to allow the user to interact with the content inside the div window (since everything is just the click-to-drag area). I mainly used the code from the example http://interactjs.io/ (pasting here for reference):

```
<div class="resize-container">
  <div class="resize-drag">
     Resize from any edge or corner
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the js:

```
interact('.resize-drag')
  .draggable({
    onmove: window.dragMoveListener
  })
  .resizable({
    preserveAspectRatio: true,
    edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true }
  })
  .on('resizemove', function (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);

    // update the element's style
    target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

    // translate when resizing from top or left edges
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '×' + Math.round(event.rect.height);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out in a very simple way. My problem is just this: How to make only parts of a div draggable? Usually when you do something like:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div> I want to be dragged if this is clicked </div>
    <div> I do not want to be dragged if this is clicked</div>
</div>
```

The whole `#draggable` div is set to draggable so you cannot really interact with the contents of the div. However, with jQuery I did the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <style>
      #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
      </style>
      <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
          <div style="border: 4px solid black" onmouseover="$( '#draggable' ).draggable('enable');" onmouseout="$( '#draggable' ).draggable('disable');">
                click here to drag this thing
          </div>
          <p>Do not want to drag if click here</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When your mouse is over the top div the draggable is enabled and you are able to move the div. Otherwise is just like any other div with content.